# Link in iframe has been clicked — getting it's location

Tags: php, jquery, iframe, location, same-origin-policy

My aim is building prototype of something more like a browser. Basically: address bar is always on top and it is sending queries to search engines and open links in an area right under it.

I've taken the following path: having an address bar as a regular div and placing content opening with queries to the iframe, placed right under "address bar".

If someone knows a better solution of this problem, I would love to hear it.

Due to same-origin policy we can't get any data from this iframe. So I've managed to send separate query using PHP curl parsing whole page and get the Title, yay!

Now something I just can't do: I need to get the location of the link, clicked in iframe. It doesn't matter how will it work, and it can be any kind of trick or crutch or whatever.

May be it is impossible, but, probably, anyone has any clue?

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, for security reasons web browsers are blocking access to the data in `<iframe>`

Comment: Thanks, I've mentioned this as well. Point is to find any sort of trick how to handle it like I've done with titles. There is even browser written in java script called breach, solution should be available.